# How can I get a Terminal-here button added to Finder toolbar?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder

I've seen Automator and AppleScripts that open a terminal to the path of the file currently selected in a Finder window.  I think it would be more useful to me to simply have a button on the Finder toolbar that opens a terminal window to the current directory listed in the Finder.

How can I get a Terminal-here button added to the Finder toolbar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reviewed OpenTerminal here and then found ShellHere.  I chose ShellHere, compiled the source without a hitch and it does exactly what I want.
http://etresoft.org/shellhere.html

Comment: I think that [cdto](https://github.com/jbtule/cdto) is superior to ShellHere both in speed and appearance (icon). It also spares you from that `cd /very/long/path` that ShellHere shows every time. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal includes exactly this functionality as a Service. As with most Services, these are disabled by default, so you'll need to enable this to make it appear in the Services menu.

> System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services

Enable **New Terminal at Folder**. There's also **New Terminal Tab at Folder**, which will create a tab in the frontmost Terminal window (if any, else it will create a new window). These Services work in all applications, not just Finder, and they operate on folders as well as absolute pathnames selected in text.

You can even assign command keys to them.

Services appear in the Services submenu of each application menu, and within the contextual menu (Control-Click or Right-Click on a folder or pathname).

In addition, Lion Terminal will open a new terminal window if you drag a folder (or pathname) onto the Terminal application icon, and you can also drag to the tab bar of an existing window to create a new tab.

Finally, if you drag a folder or pathname onto a tab (in the tab bar) and the foreground process is the shell, it will automatically execute a "cd" command. (Dragging into the terminal view within the tab merely inserts the pathname on its own, as in older versions of Terminal.)

On a related note, Lion Terminal also has new Services for looking up man pages: **Open man page in Terminal** displays the selected man page topic in a new terminal window, and **Search man Pages in Terminal** performs "apropos" on the selected text. The former also understands man page references ("open(2)"), man page command line arguments ("2 open") and man page URLs ("x-man-page://2/open").

Answer (score 5):

[cdto](https://github.com/jbtule/cdto) looks great and seems to be frequently maintained. They even have Mavericks and Yosemite [matching icons](https://github.com/jbtule/cdto/issues/9) (you have to install them manually).

ShellHere has a horrible icon (and adds the `cd /you/long/folder/path/here` as the first command to the terminal, which is super annoying).

Comment: thanks, this app rocks

Answer (score 2):

[OpenInTerminal](https://github.com/Ji4n1ng/OpenInTerminal) and [Go2Shell](https://apps.apple.com/app/id445770608) will be ideal solutions.

Comment: openinterminal-lite worked for me https://github.com/Ji4n1ng/OpenInTerminal/blob/master/Resources/README-Lite.md

Answer (score 1):

> *To add 'Terminal-here' button to the Finder toolbar:*

I chose Go2Shell -- it lives as a button on my Finder toolbar. And, it's free.

Get it :

```
Go2Shell on the Mac App Store: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/go2shell/id445770608 

Go2Shell at ZipZapMac: http://zipzapmac.com/Go2Shell
```

Install it :

```
...

Browse to the folder containing the app. 

Locate the file 'Go2Shell.app' and Command ⌘-drag it into the Finder toolbar
```

Configure it :

```
open -a Go2Shell --args config
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Path Finder? (http://www.cocoatech.com/).
It does that and much more... It's not a button added to Finder, but it's a very powerful Finder replacement.

Comment: Thanks.  I've seen that app before.  I thought about trying it, but felt it would probably degrade system performance.  On your recommendation, I reviewed it again and searched for other people's experience with it.  There was a time when it did have some performance problems.  Perhaps those are cleared up now.  I may buy it yet.